# I want to validate records i have in .dat file and records inserted to database after running ctl file

Tags: plsql

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_record_count (
p_file_name IN VARCHAR2,
p_table_name IN VARCHAR2
) AS
v_file_record_count NUMBER;
v_db_record_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
-- Step 1: Determine the number of records in the file
v_file_record_count := 0;

```
-- Open and read the file to count records (adjust this part based on your file format)
```

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_file_record_count FROM EXTERNAL (p_file_name)
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER DEFAULT DIRECTORY datafile_dir
ACCESS PARAMETERS (
RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET 'UTF8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
) LOCATION ('file_name.txt');

```
-- Step 2: Determine the number of records in the database table
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_db_record_count FROM p_table_name;

-- Step 3: Compare the counts and raise an exception if they don't match
IF v_file_record_count <> v_db_record_count THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Validation failed: Record counts do not match.');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Validation successful: Record counts match.');
END IF;
```

END validate_record_count;
/

Is it correct to follow this or we need to have a different approach

Comment: What do you mean after running ctl file? Are you loading the file via sqlldr? I see you are using an Inline External Table in the procedure to count the number of records in a file. Is the idea to load the file via sqlldr and then separately check the record count of the same file using an external table and make sure the number of rows loaded via sqlldr matches the record count from the external table?

The line for Step 2 will not work, you can't select from a P_TABLE_NAME varchar2 parameter. You would need to use dynamic sql instead.